# How scan angle is measured and published in LaserScan msg?

Tags: ros, navigation, 3d-navigation, gmapping, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Range of the distance of the obstacles are measured from output of laser sensor but how actually the scan angles are measured. do we use any separate sensor to get the value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207425/how-scan-angle-is-measured-and-published-in-laserscan-msg?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The scan angles depend on the angle_increment and angle_min values stored into the topic (as you can see [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html)). i.e.: if angle_increment is set to 0.1 (rad) the first range measurement is refered to `angle_min + 0*0.1`  , the second to `angle_min + 1*0.1` rad, the third to `angle_min+2*0.1` rad and so on.
In general, the angle refered to a particular range measurement is

```
angle = angle_min + index*angle_increment
```

where `index` is refered to the index of the vector's element containing that range measurement.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3